# Restricting type of Camera in 'change camera" button in CameraCaptureUI

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

CameraCaptureUI is a easy way to capture,record video from the camera.
I am Working on Camera App where I use only particular camera say for example, Only Logitech camera be displayed. So when the user press 'change camera" In UI, it will only switch between Logitech camera not others.

I can do it using Media Capture UI.I wanted to know whether it is possible through CameraCapture UI Api or not Since this will reduce the development time.

I am using C++ as programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be an option on the CameraCaptureUI - it really is pretty simplified. If you are going with the MediaCapture/CaptureElement route - you might want to check the [CameraCaptureControl](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17626#326623) in the WinRT XAML Toolkit. It is C# code, but it has some things figured out for controlling the cameras.